# How come ie8's zoom expands div at a different ratio than it expands text?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, zooming

Basically, when I zoom in on text it messes up my formatting. It seems like the text zoom zoom at a different rate than the yellow box zoom.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Below is the sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
            <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
                <style>
                .highlightLine
                {
                    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
                    opacity: 0.5;
                    background-color: #e8e800;
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: 1;
                    -moz-user-select: none;
                }

                .clickAbleTable
                {
                    border-width: 0px;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    position: relative;
                }

                .zeroAll
                {
                    padding: 0px;
                    margin: 0px;
                    border: 0px;
                }
            </style>

    </head>
    <body class="zeroAll">
        <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; FONT-SIZE: 100%" id=container name="container" class="zeroAll">
            <TABLE style="WIDTH: 100%" class="clickAbleTable zeroAll">
                <TBODY class="zeroAll">
                    <TR class="zeroAll">
                        <TD class="zeroAll"><PRE class="zeroAll">This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. </PRE></TD></TR>
                    <TR class="zeroAll">
                        <TD class="zeroAll"><PRE class="zeroAll">This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. </PRE></TD></TR>
                    <TR class="zeroAll">
                        <TD class="zeroAll"><PRE class="zeroAll">This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. </PRE></TD></TR>
                    <TR class="zeroAll">
                        <TD class="zeroAll"><PRE class="zeroAll">This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. </PRE></TD></TR>
                    <TR class="zeroAll">
                        <TD class="zeroAll"><PRE class="zeroAll">This is sample text. This is sample text. </PRE></TD></TR>
                    <TR class="zeroAll">
                        <TD class="zeroAll"><PRE class="zeroAll">This is sample text. This is sample text. </PRE></TD></TR>
                    <TR class="zeroAll">
                        <TD class="zeroAll"><PRE class="zeroAll">This is sample text. </PRE></TD></TR>
                    <TR class="zeroAll">
                        <TD class="zeroAll"><PRE class="zeroAll">This is sample text. </PRE></TD></TR>
                    <TR class="zeroAll">
                        <TD class="zeroAll"><PRE class="zeroAll">This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. </PRE></TD></TR>
                    <TR class="zeroAll">
                        <TD class="zeroAll"><PRE class="zeroAll">This is sample text. This is sample text. This is sample text. </PRE></TD></TR>
                    </TBODY>
            </TABLE>

            <DIV style="WIDTH: 10px; DISPLAY: block; HEIGHT: 100%; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 140px" id=colMark_80_4 class=highlightLine>
            </DIV>
            <DIV style="WIDTH: 10px; DISPLAY: block; HEIGHT: 100%; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 5.55%" id=colMark_80_5 class=highlightLine>
            </DIV>
        </DIV>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: The yellow lines should stay on either side of the word sample.

Comment: The zoom algorithm is crap. You can't really fix it.

Comment: How come the text doesn't double in size?

Comment: @Diodeus  I noticed ie8 mode is better than ie7 mode, but still crap.

Comment: @Diodeus you spelled IE wrong

Answer (score 0):

IE has different algorithms for text and static elements versus positioned elements and floats. The [adaptive zoom](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/25/internet-explorer-8-and-adaptive-zoom.aspx) algorithm works as such for text and static elements:

> Dimension scaling is one of the most important improvements in IE8’s Adaptive Zoom. Dimensions specified using absolute units (e.g.: in, cm, mm, etc) or device and font dependent units (e.g.: px, ex, em, etc) are scaled as per the zoom level. Therefore, at 200%, 100px becomes 200px and 20pt becomes 40pt.
>   Content-dependent dimensions, i.e. percent and auto, are not scaled as they are computed during layout. Therefore, at 200%, a width of 50% of the viewport does not become 100% of the same. This is a marked change from Zoom in IE7.

And as such for positioned elements and floats:

> Positioned elements grow and shrink like in-flow elements. However their new position is determined by the properties set, and the offsets used. Similarly, floats will be positioned with respect to their container as per the normal rules of CSS. If the width of the container changes with zoom, then the position of the float will change. Zooming of adjacent floats is exactly like resizing the window – if the width of the viewport is not large enough to accommodate the floats, the last one in markup will drop to the next line.

Use the following meta tag in IE10 to fix the scaling while in IE8 compatibility mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-TextLayoutMetrics" content="natural" />
```

**References**

- [Layout Zoom Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265030#opticalzoom)
- [Optical Zooming in Legacy Document Modes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/08/28/optical-zooming-in-legacy-document-modes.aspx)